# Xcode 7 UI tests Access Bar Button Item

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

Im trying new xcode ui tests and get the following error

```
func testLogout() {

    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let tablesQuery = app.tables
    let passwordSecureTextField = tablesQuery/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.secureTextFields["Password"]/*[[".cells.secureTextFields[\"Password\"]",".secureTextFields[\"Password\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
    passwordSecureTextField.tap()
    passwordSecureTextField/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.pressForDuration(1.2);/*[[".tap()",".pressForDuration(1.2);"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
    app/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.menuItems["Paste"]/*[[".menus.menuItems[\"Paste\"]",".menuItems[\"Paste\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/.tap()

    let poReceiverNavigationBar = app.navigationBars["PO Receiver"]
    poReceiverNavigationBar.buttons["Login"].tap()

    let menuIcoButton = poReceiverNavigationBar.buttons["menu ico"]
    menuIcoButton.tap()
```

the error is

```
no maches found for "menu ico" Button
```

in fact its custom Bar Button item and its not connected via IBOutlet. The question is can i access that button in some other way via coordinates or smth ? or maybe some other solution

Comment: Did you get the identifier for that button through recording? What happens why you try by `staticTexts[]`?

Comment: oh, can you tell me how to  get the identifier for that button through recording? please_)

Comment: [Check out this blog post from mokacoding](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/xcode-7-ui-testing/), second image down shows you. Also has a lot of information on getting started

Comment: yeap ive generated code through recording..

Comment: Have you tried setting an `accessibilityIdentifier` on the button? This can be done via code or Interface Builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can select by specific coordinates:

```
    extension XCUIElement {
        func tapAtPosition(let position: CGPoint) {
            let cooridnate = self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)).coordinateWithOffset(CGVector(dx: position.x, dy: position.y))
            cooridnate.tap()
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey, what is the type of self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset?

Comment: yeap, ive just did the same :)